# query that for each position bring the id of the employee with the lowest salary

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

need to create a query in Oracle's SQL that for each JOB, return the employee ID with the lowest SALARY.

I tried like this, but it brought me all SALARIES and ID:

```
SELECT JOB, MIN(SAL) FROM EMP
    GROUP BY EMPNO, JOB;
```

And so it brings me only the lowest salary of all:

```
SELECT JOB, SAL 
    FROM SCOTT_EMP 
    WHERE SAL = (SELECT MIN(SAL) FROM EMP);
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want one more column, you could use the `keep` syntax:

```
select
    job,
    min(sal),
    min(id) keep(dense_rank first order by sal) id
from emp
group by job
```

For more columns, you can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select e.*, rank() over(partition by job order by sal) rn
    from emp e
) e
where rn = 1
```

Comment: `select *
from (
    select e.*, rank() over(partition by job order by sal) rn
    from emp e
) e
where rn = 1`

This query answered me! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want to show the data of the employee with the lowest salary for each given occupation, correct? In this case, we can use `GROUP BY` to *group by* our occupations, and `ORDER BY` to order by our salaries.

**Sample data example:**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_employees(id int(11), name varchar(100), occupation varchar(100));
CREATE TABLE tbl_salary(id int(11), salary decimal);

INSERT INTO tbl_employees VALUES(1, "John Doe", "Accountant");
INSERT INTO tbl_employees VALUES(2, "Christopher Stark", "Accountant");
INSERT INTO tbl_employees VALUES(3, "Arnold  Sanders", "Accountant");
INSERT INTO tbl_employees VALUES(4, "Jane Doe", "Marketer");
INSERT INTO tbl_employees VALUES(5, "Christina Lavine", "Marketer");
INSERT INTO tbl_employees VALUES(6, "Penny Lane", "Marketer");
INSERT INTO tbl_employees VALUES(7, "George Franklin", "Customer Support");

INSERT INTO tbl_employees VALUES(8, "Kent Brockmann", "Customer Support");
INSERT INTO tbl_employees VALUES(9, "Richard Felenski", "Customer Support");
INSERT INTO tbl_employees VALUES(10, "Patrick Neil", "Technical Support");
INSERT INTO tbl_employees VALUES(11, "Paul Richards", "Technical Support");
INSERT INTO tbl_employees VALUES(12, "Tom Harris", "Technical Support");
INSERT INTO tbl_employees VALUES(13, "Rebecca Moore", "Project Manager");
INSERT INTO tbl_employees VALUES(14, "Laura Cross", "Project Manager");
INSERT INTO tbl_employees VALUES(15, "Denise McIntyre", "Project Manager");

INSERT INTO tbl_salary VALUES(1, 100.00);
INSERT INTO tbl_salary VALUES(2, 150.00);
INSERT INTO tbl_salary VALUES(3, 300.00);
INSERT INTO tbl_salary VALUES(4, 110.00);
INSERT INTO tbl_salary VALUES(5, 120.00);
INSERT INTO tbl_salary VALUES(6, 235.00);
INSERT INTO tbl_salary VALUES(7, 240.00);
INSERT INTO tbl_salary VALUES(8, 200.00);
INSERT INTO tbl_salary VALUES(9, 160.00);
INSERT INTO tbl_salary VALUES(10, 230.00);
INSERT INTO tbl_salary VALUES(11, 320.00);
INSERT INTO tbl_salary VALUES(12, 150.00);
INSERT INTO tbl_salary VALUES(13, 168.00);
INSERT INTO tbl_salary VALUES(14, 175.00);
INSERT INTO tbl_salary VALUES(15, 350.00);
```

**The query:**

```
SELECT
  tbl_employees.id as emp_id,
  tbl_employees.name as emp_name,
  tbl_employees.occupation as emp_pos,
  tbl_salary.salary as emp_salary
FROM
  tbl_employees
INNER JOIN
  tbl_salary ON tbl_employees.id = tbl_salary.id
GROUP BY
  tbl_employees.occupation
ORDER BY
  tbl_salary.salary DESC
```

This should give you each employee with the lowest salary within each respectable occupation.

**Output:**
[image]

Working fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d4a35f/5).

Comment: I understand your logic applied to the query, however, I only need the employee ID with the lowest salary for each department.